# QGIS 1.8.0 on Mac - how to cut/paste/delete?

Tags: qgis, editing, mac

I have a line vector layer selected, editing is on, I select one vector (a dozen points) with the node select tool so the vertices are red squares.

1. the cut icon is greyed out, command/X does nothing, delete part isn't greyed out but does nothing; so I can't cut/copy/delete it
2. I select a vertex so its square turns to blue, then hit the delete key - nothing happens. Remember, a PC delete key is forward delete, back delete is the backspace key; a Mac has no forward delete, the delete key is a back delete; is this the problem or is it related to 1.?
3. I can't select more than one vector by holding down the control key (or shift or command - I've tried everything I can think of) - when I click on the second vector the first is deselected. Again, is this a Mac-only problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using the node tool, when you select a node it turns blue. Then, hold the [fn] key and then press [delete]. That will emulate the [Delete] key on Windoxs/Unix. I just tested this on 1.8 on a MacBook Pro.

**EDIT:**
For point #3, you can select multiple vectors (also called features) with one of the "Select Features" tools. Here is a picture of the options:

[image]

To pick multiple features you will want one of the bottom four tools. Note that if you are using the top tool (Select Single Feature) it only lets you pick one at a time.

Comment: Good - one thing works! Many thanks. But no, in 3 I meant vector, to merge two vectors (unsplit them).

Comment: Now I understand! I edited the answer to address that part of your question.

Comment: Looks great, except that I can't find any of those select features at all...

Comment: FOund them - under View! (not edit or vector or ...) And now the cut copy etc. are active, so 1 & 3 are answered too. Many thanks, katahdin.